# Exposing properties of an embedded object in VBA Class

Tags: vba, inheritance

I am writing an extension class for the `ComboBox` control.
This extension has a number of additional properties, methods and events.
I made the embedded `ComboBox` object the default member (using the `Attribute Value.VB_UserMemId = 0` trick) in hope that I could use something like:

`myClassInstance.ListIndex`

to access the properties and methods of the embedded `ComboBox` control. However, it is not working. I get compiler error:

> Method or data member not found.

Is there any way to directly expose all of the properties and methods of the embedded control without having to write proxy `Let`/`Set`/`Get` properties and `Sub`/`Function` for the embedded members?

Comment: Default properties effectively only work for *value* type properties.  As you have found, having an object-type as your default property does not work.  Simply make the embedded ComboBox an explicit property and then access it like `myClassInstance.ComboBox.ListIndex`.